# Why is there a delay when sending data to SIMULINK TCP/IP receive block?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, matlab, sockets

Hi I'm trying to send data from simulink to a c++ program, and then send it back as part of a larger program. I've attached the code here. The problem is in the write function of sock_send class. When printing to screen, value from data_o is perfect and appears normal, but while sending it using the linux "send" function, the values are very delayed. They only appear after sometime in the simulink scope. I think I'm missing something very trivial. Any help would be appreciated.

This is my main program.

```
#include "sock_send.h" 
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

extern std::mutex some_other_mutex;

int main(){

    int portno[2] = {55011, 55021};
    double pdiesel ={0.002};

    sock_send newsocket1;
    sock_send newsocket2;

    newsocket1.startsocket(portno[0]);
    newsocket2.startsocket(portno[1]);

    std::thread t1 (&sock_send::readsocket, &newsocket1, std::ref(pdiesel));

    std::thread t2 (&sock_send::writesocket, &newsocket2, std::ref(pdiesel));


    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return 0;

}
```

The sock_send.h program

```
#ifndef SOCK_SEND_H
#define SOCK_SEND_H

#include <functional>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

extern std::mutex some_other_mutex;


class sock_send
{

public:

    void startsocket (int portno);
    void writesocket(double & data_o);
    void readsocket(double & data_in);
    ~sock_send();

private:
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    int n, epfd, sockfd, yes=1, newsockfd = 0, nbytess,
    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
    // define epoll event structs
    struct epoll_event event, *events = new epoll_event;


};
#endif
```

and the sock_send.cc program

```
#include "sock_send.h"

std::mutex some_other_mutex;

void sock_send::startsocket (int portno){

    //create an epoll file descriptor
        if ((epfd = epoll_create1(0)) == -1)
        std::cout << "Error on epoll create\t" << errno << std::endl;

    //create the socket file descriptor
    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM | SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0)) == -1) 
        std::cout << "Error on socket create\t" << errno << std::endl;

        // get rid of annoying port in use
    if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof yes) == -1) 
        std::cout << "Error on socket reuse option\t" << errno << std::endl;

    // fill up serv addr with zeros
        bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

        //enter data in serv addr
        serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    // bind port and ip to socket 1
    if ((bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr))) == -1) 
        std::cout << "Error on binding sock\t" << errno << std::endl;

        //start listening on socket           
    if ((listen(sockfd,100))==-1)
        std::cout << "Error on listen sock\t" << errno << std::endl;

    // socket epoll control
    event.data.fd = sockfd;
    event.events = EPOLLIN;

    if ((epoll_ctl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, sockfd, &event)) == -1) 
        std::cout << "Error on epoll ctl sock\t" << errno << std::endl;

        while (newsockfd == 0){     

        // wait for an event using epoll
            if ((n = epoll_wait (epfd, events, 20, -1)) == -1){
            std::cout << "Error on epoll wait\t" << errno << std::endl;
            continue;
        }
        if (sockfd == events[0].data.fd){   

            // accept incoming connection
                if ((newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr,(socklen_t*)&clilen)) == -1){
                std::cout << "Error on accept\t " << errno << std::endl;
                continue;
            }
            event.data.fd = newsockfd;                  
            event.events = EPOLLIN;
                if ((epoll_ctl (epfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, newsockfd, &event)) == -1){
                std::cout << "Error on epoll cntl" << errno << std::endl;
                continue;
            }
            break;
        }

        else
            std::cout << "Epoll returning some other socket \t" << events[0].data.fd << std::endl;
    }
}

void sock_send::readsocket(double & data_in){
    while (1){  

        // wait for an event using epoll
            if ((n = epoll_wait (epfd, events, 20, 0)) == -1){
            std::cout << "Error on epoll wait\t" << errno << std::endl;
            continue;
        }

        //if newsock connections available
        if (newsockfd == events[0].data.fd){

            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck (some_other_mutex);
            nbytess = recv(events[0].data.fd, &data_in , sizeof data_in, 0);
            lck.unlock();
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(1000));                                       
            if (nbytess == -1){
                std::cout << "Error during read: " << errno << std::endl;
                break;
            }

            if (nbytess == 0){
                std::cout << "End of data from this socket" << std::endl;
                break;
            }    
        }
    }
}


void sock_send::writesocket(double & data_o){
    while(1){
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck (some_other_mutex);
        nbytess = send(newsockfd, &data_o, sizeof data_o, 0);
        std::cout << data_o << "\t" << data_o<< "\t" << sizeof data_o << std::endl;
        lck.unlock();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(1000));                                           
        if (nbytess == -1){
            if (errno == 104)
                std::cout << "Connection Closed" << std::endl;
            else
                std::cout << "Error during write: " << errno << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

sock_send::~sock_send()
{   
    delete events;
    close (sockfd);
}
```

and the simulink model

[simulink model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kv6n3.png)

Remote addresses are both localhost, port nos as given in main, byte order is little Endian, sample times for sine wave and tcp rx block are 1e-3 and simulation time is 10 secs

edit:

I figured out how to remedy the issue by using

```
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(1));
```

instead of

```
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(1000));
```

in the writesocket function. The issue still stands though as I'm not sure why it happens. All my sampling times are 1 millisecond. I guess there is a deadlock situation occurring? I would be grateful if someone could provide an explanation.

Comment: How much is  "very delayed" ? 10 miliseconds ? 100 miliseconds ? 10 seconds ?

Comment: The sample time of the sine wave is 1milisecond, but when I receive it on the TCP/IP block its about 1 second. I guess delayed is not the right word. It's more like the sine wave frequency is reduced.

Comment: If your c++ program is designed to just read from a socket, process the data, and write to a different socket (or the same socket, it doesn't matter), then you should have a single threaded application. You should not be using std::thread at all.