# Accessing a value passed by reference into a thread in c++11

Tags: c++, linux, matlab, c++11, simulink

I'm trying to access a value that I've passed by reference into a thread that will run until the end of the program. I want to perform some operations on this value and then pass it by reference to another thread.

I've looked into thread futures but I'm not sure that suits my purpose as I need constant updates on the value. If I just use normal mutexes, my operation never gets called due to blocking by the other threads accessing the value. (this is why I've used the atomic bool flag for the functions in the class). Any advice on how exactly to proceed? Here's my code.

main program

```
#include "sock_send.h" 
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>

extern std::mutex some_other_mutex;

int main(){

    int portno[4] = {55011, 55016, 55021, 55026};
    std::vector <double> data_r(6), data_l(6);
    std::atomic <bool> flag1(false), flag2(false);

    sock_send newsocket1;   
    sock_send newsocket3;

    newsocket1.startsocket(portno[0]);  
    newsocket3.startsocket(portno[2]);

    std::thread t1 (&sock_send::readsocket, &newsocket1, std::ref(data_r), std::ref(flag1));
```

**// do some operation on data_r, say data_l = data_r/10;**

```
    std::thread t3 (&sock_send::writesocket, &newsocket3, std::ref(data_l), std::ref(flag1));

    t1.join();  

    t3.detach();    

    return 0;

}
```

sock_send.h

```
#ifndef SOCK_SEND_H
#define SOCK_SEND_H

#include <functional>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>

extern std::mutex some_other_mutex;

class sock_send
{
public:

    void startsocket (int portno);
    void writesocket(std::vector<double> & data_o, std::atomic <bool> &flag);
    void readsocket(std::vector<double> & data_in, std::atomic <bool> &flag);
    ~sock_send();

private:
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    int n, epfd, sockfd, yes=1, newsockfd = 0, nbytess,
    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
    // define epoll event structs
    struct epoll_event event, *events = new epoll_event;
};
#endif
```

sock_send.cc

```
#include "sock_send.h"

std::mutex some_other_mutex;

void sock_send::startsocket (int portno){

    //create an epoll file descriptor
        if ((epfd = epoll_create1(0)) == -1)
        std::cout << "Error on epoll create\t" << errno << std::endl;

    //create the socket file descriptor
    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM | SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0)) == -1) 
        std::cout << "Error on socket create\t" << errno << std::endl;

        // get rid of annoying port in use
    if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof yes) == -1) 
        std::cout << "Error on socket reuse option\t" << errno << std::endl;

    // fill up serv addr with zeros
        bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

        //enter data in serv addr
        serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    // bind port and ip to socket 1
    if ((bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr))) == -1) 
        std::cout << "Error on binding sock\t" << errno << std::endl;

        //start listening on socket           
    if ((listen(sockfd,100))==-1)
        std::cout << "Error on listen sock\t" << errno << std::endl;

    // socket epoll control
    event.data.fd = sockfd;
    event.events = EPOLLIN;

    if ((epoll_ctl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, sockfd, &event)) == -1) 
        std::cout << "Error on epoll ctl sock\t" << errno << std::endl;

        while (newsockfd == 0){     

        // wait for an event using epoll
            if ((n = epoll_wait (epfd, events, 20, -1)) == -1){
            std::cout << "Error on epoll wait\t" << errno << std::endl;
            continue;
        }
        if (sockfd == events[0].data.fd){   

            // accept incoming connection
                if ((newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr,(socklen_t*)&clilen)) == -1){
                std::cout << "Error on accept\t " << errno << std::endl;
                continue;
            }
            event.data.fd = newsockfd;                  
            event.events = EPOLLIN;
                if ((epoll_ctl (epfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, newsockfd, &event)) == -1){
                std::cout << "Error on epoll cntl" << errno << std::endl;
                continue;
            }
            break;
        }

        else
            std::cout << "Epoll returning some other socket \t" << events[0].data.fd << std::endl;
    }
}

void sock_send::readsocket(std::vector<double> & data_in, std::atomic <bool> &flag){
    while (1){  

        // wait for an event using epoll
            if ((n = epoll_wait (epfd, events, 20, 0)) == -1){
            std::cout << "Error on epoll wait\t" << errno << std::endl;
            continue;
        }


        //if newsock connections available
        if ((newsockfd == events[0].data.fd) & (flag ==false)){
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck (some_other_mutex);
            nbytess = recv(events[0].data.fd, data_in.data() , (sizeof data_in[0])*(data_in.size()), 0);
            lck.unlock();
            flag = true;
            if (nbytess == -1){
                std::cout << "Error during read: " << errno << std::endl;
                break;
            }

            if (nbytess == 0){
                std::cout << "End of data from this socket" << std::endl;
                break;
            }    
        }
    }
}


void sock_send::writesocket(std::vector<double> & data_o, std::atomic <bool> &flag){
    while(1){ 
        if (flag == true ){
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck (some_other_mutex);
            nbytess = send(newsockfd, data_o.data(),(sizeof data_o[0])*(data_o.size()), 0);
            lck.unlock();
            flag =false;
            if (nbytess == -1){
                if (errno == 104)
                    std::cout << "Connection Closed" << std::endl;
                else
                    std::cout << "Error during write: " << errno << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
}

sock_send::~sock_send()
{   
    delete events;
    close (sockfd);
}
```

<<<<<<<<<<< edit: new single thread code>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

main

```
#include "sock_send.h" 
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

int main(){

    int portno[2] = {55011, 55021};
    std::vector<double> data_mod(6);

    sock_send newsocket1;   

    newsocket1.startsocket(portno,2);   

    for (double i=0; i<9993999; i++){
        newsocket1.read(data_mod);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::nanoseconds(1)); 
        newsocket1.write(data_mod);
    }       

    return 0;

}
```

sock_send.h

```
#ifndef SOCK_SEND_H
#define SOCK_SEND_H

#include <functional>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>

class sock_send
{
public:

    void startsocket (int * portno, int np);
    void read(std::vector<double> &data_in);
    void write(std::vector<double> &data_o);
    ~sock_send();

private:
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr[2], cli_addr[2];
    int n[2], epfd[2], sockfd[2], yes=1, newsockfd[2] = {0,0}, nbytess[2],
    clilen[2] = {sizeof(cli_addr[0]), sizeof(cli_addr[1])};
    // define epoll event structs
    struct epoll_event event[2], *events[2] = {new epoll_event, new epoll_event};
};
#endif
```

sock_send.cc

```
#include "sock_send.h"

void sock_send::startsocket (int *portno, int np){

for (int i = 0; i <np; i++){
    //create an epoll file descriptor
        if ((epfd[i] = epoll_create1(0)) == -1)
        std::cout << "Error on epoll create\t" << errno << std::endl;

    //create the socket file descriptor
    if ((sockfd[i] = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM | SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0)) == -1) 
        std::cout << "Error on socket create\t" << errno << std::endl;

        // get rid of annoying port in use
    if (setsockopt(sockfd[i], SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof yes) == -1) 
        std::cout << "Error on socket reuse option\t" << errno << std::endl;

    // fill up serv addr with zeros
        bzero((char *) &serv_addr[i], sizeof(serv_addr[i]));

        //enter data in serv addr
        serv_addr[i].sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr[i].sin_port = htons(portno[i]);
    serv_addr[i].sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    // bind port and ip to socket 1
    if ((bind(sockfd[i], (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr[i], sizeof(serv_addr[i]))) == -1) 
        std::cout << "Error on binding sock\t" << errno << std::endl;

        //start listening on socket           
    if ((listen(sockfd[i],100))==-1)
        std::cout << "Error on listen sock\t" << errno << std::endl;

    // socket epoll control
    event[i].data.fd = sockfd[i];
    event[i].events = EPOLLIN;

    if ((epoll_ctl(epfd[i], EPOLL_CTL_ADD, sockfd[i], &event[i])) == -1) 
        std::cout << "Error on epoll ctl sock\t" << errno << std::endl;

        while (newsockfd[i] == 0){  

        // wait for an event using epoll
            if ((n[i] = epoll_wait (epfd[i], events[i], 20, -1)) == -1){
            std::cout << "Error on epoll wait\t" << errno << std::endl;
            continue;
        }
        if (sockfd[i] == events[i][0].data.fd){ 

            // accept incoming connection
                if ((newsockfd[i] = accept(sockfd[i], (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr[i],(socklen_t*)&clilen[i])) == -1){
                std::cout << "Error on accept\t " << errno << std::endl;
                continue;
            }
            event[i].data.fd = newsockfd[i];                    
            event[i].events = EPOLLIN;
                if ((epoll_ctl (epfd[i], EPOLL_CTL_ADD, newsockfd[i], &event[i])) == -1){
                std::cout << "Error on epoll cntl" << errno << std::endl;
                continue;
            }
            break;
        }

        else
            std::cout << "Epoll returning some other socket \t" << events[i][0].data.fd << std::endl;
    }
}
}

void sock_send::read(std::vector<double> &data_in){
    // wait for an event using epoll
        if ((n[0] = epoll_wait (epfd[0], events[0], 20, 0)) == -1){
        std::cout << "Error on epoll wait\t" << errno << std::endl;
    }


    //if newsock connections available
    if ((newsockfd[0] == events[0][0].data.fd)){
        nbytess[0] = recv(events[0][0].data.fd, data_in.data() , (sizeof data_in[0])*(data_in.size()), 0);
        if (nbytess[0] == -1){
            std::cout << "Error during read: " << errno << std::endl;
        }

        if (nbytess[0] == 0){
            std::cout << "End of data from this socket" << std::endl;
        }
        //std::cout << data_in[0] << std::endl;
    }
}

void sock_send::write(std::vector<double> &data_o){
        std::cout << data_o[0] << std::endl;        
    nbytess[1] = send(newsockfd[1], data_o.data(),(sizeof data_o[0])*(data_o.size()), 0); 
    if (nbytess[1] == -1){
        if (errno == 104)
            std::cout << "Connection Closed" << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "Error during write: " << errno << std::endl;
    }
}

sock_send::~sock_send()
{   
    delete events[0], events[1];
    close (sockfd[0]);
    close (sockfd[1]);
}
```

Comment: I'm basically looking for a way to interrupt and block the other threads while I do my operation before releasing control back to them. Kind of the opposite of conditional variables where a thread waits for a condition to be true before executing, here I want the thread to execute until I want priority for another thread.

Comment: You should ask yourself why do you have 1 thread that is reading the data, one thread that is modifying the data and one thread that is writing the data? That sounds like a single thread.

Comment: Hi mark, I need different threads as the sockets I read and write to are connected to different ports. I read values from a port, want to perform an operation and then send the values out another port. To make it simpler, I've wrapped all functionality in a single class. And I have multiple instances of this running. The above code shows just one read-modify write.

Comment: Also the modification is non trivial, I've just given an example of  divide by 10. The data is passed to another program which performs some simulations based on the value and then returns something to be sent back.

Comment: I still don't understand why you need 3 threads, when this is a classic one thread problem. The thread reads from the socket, modifies the data, and sends to a different socket.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your suggestion. I did make everything work in a single thread like you suggested. I've updated the code above to show this. However I now have a peculiar problem similar to the other question I've asked on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40981760/why-is-there-a-delay-when-sending-data-to-simulink-tcp-ip-recieve-block Unless I add   std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::nanoseconds(1));  in the main function, my values do not get passed to simulink. I think it is some kind of race condition, but since we have one thread I don't see how that is possible.

Comment: I really don't understand what you are intending to do. You are accepting socket connections in the socket thread, but reading and writing from the main thread. All IO should be done in one thread. I can't really offer suggestions because I really can't figure out what you are trying to do.

Comment: What I need to do is accept 2 socket connections at first and then whenever my third party program calls the read function, read the data. It will do some manipulations to the data and then call the write function to send data back through another socket. The for loop is there to simulate the constant read and write operation off the third party program. It is upto that other program when it wants to read/modify/write. It might do it once, twice or a hundred times. Isn't there only one thread now? the main thread? I'm not spawning any new ones and the program should run in sequence.

Comment: sorry, that's more complicated than I have time to deal with.